# Entanglement entropy vs entropy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, entropy, quantum-entanglement, entanglement-entropy

I just read that if you have a pure density matrix state on a product space, then a way to define entropy in a subspace is to take the reduced density matrix state and define $S = 1- \mathrm{tr}(\rho^2),$ which measures somehow the degree of entanglement. My question is: How is this definition related to the canonical definition of entropy, which is $S = - \mathrm{tr}( \rho \log( \rho))$? Are they related or different concepts?

Comment: Where did you see the entropy of entanglement defined as $S = 1- \mathrm{tr}(\rho^2)$? That seems rather nonstandard; most resources I know of use the von Neumann entropy as defined in e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_of_entanglement#Von_Neumann_entanglement_entropy).

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. It was in this paper on page 2 in the first few sentences below the diagram http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.4585v2.pdf

Comment: $S=1-tr(\rho^2)$ is not the entropy, but the "linear entropy" (as also called this way in the paper). See the Wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_entropy which also discusses your question.